# Como deixar o form estático na hora da impressão (sem alterar o tamanho)?

Tags: php, html, css

Quando mando um form para imprimir ele muda o tamanho conforme o tamanho da página, no meu caso é um cartão 54mm de largura e 84mm de altura, eu coloco essas medidas no meu código.
Ele cria a página, consigo isolar os cartões, problema que ele auto-resize para o tamanho da folha, aí acontece que quando eu pego pela impressora a4 ele fica com um tamanho, quando eu coloco na do cartão ele fica bem pequeno...Estou usando o media print para fazer o que preciso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consulta Código - Resposta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style type="text/css">
  @media print
{
    * {-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}
}
 @media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printable, #printable * {
    visibility: visible;


  }


} 
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 120px;margin-left: 120px">

<form id="printable" style="width: 5.4cm;height: 8.4cm;background-image: url(imagens/teste.png); background-size: 5.4cm 8.4cm">




                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 4.3cm;">


                        <!-- <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: imagem in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\cracha\consulta.php</b> on line <b>169</b><br />
" width="145" height="179" style="border-radius: 7px"/><br> -->
                        <center><p style='font-size: 20px'><b>FALABRETTI      </b></p></center>
                        <center><p style='font-size: 11px;margin-top: -20px;padding-left: 5px'><b>DIRCE LOURDES FALABRETTI                                                        </b></p></center>
           <!-- <div align="center" >  
<img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img
src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img
src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
src=p.gif width=1 height=46 border=0> </div> -->


                </div>









</form>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 120px">
<form  style="width: 5.7cm;height: 9cm;background-image: url(imagens/teste2.png); background-size: 5.7cm 9cm; ">




                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 7.2cm">


                        <!-- <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: imagem in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\cracha\consulta.php</b> on line <b>225</b><br />
" width="145" height="179" style="border-radius: 7px"/><br> -->
                        <!--<center><p style='font-size: 20px'><b>FALABRETTI      </b></p></center>
                        <p style='font-size: 12px;margin-top: -15px;padding-left: 37px'><b>DIRCE LOURDES FALABRETTI                                                        </b></p> -->
            <div align="center" >  
<img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img
src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img
src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img 
    src=b.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=p.gif width=5 height=46 border=0><img src=b.gif width=3 height=46 border=0><img 
src=p.gif width=1 height=46 border=0> </div>
    <center style='margin-top: -7px'><font style='font-size: 9px;color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma;'>902567          </font></center>
                </div>









</form>

</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não sei se vai resolver, mas troque tudo que estiver com medidas em % para px ou mm dentro desse `@media print` e faze um teste. Não precisa fazer de cara com seu arquivo original, criam um HTML separado apenas com um elemento com largura em % e outro em PX ou MM, depois no `@media print` vc inverte os % e PX MM e simula a impressão pra ver o que acontece. É só uma dica mesmo, agora não da pra parar pra testar isso aqui. Se der certo este método comenta ai :)

Comment: tentei fazer o que você disse (se entendi direito), eu vou por todo o meu código na pergunta

Comment: Cara abre essa página no navegador e edita a sua pergunta com o código já renderizado no browser. Vai lá da um Ctrl+U e pega o código e cola aqui. E código como vc postou dificulta pra gente fazer os testes etc.

Comment: pronto, alterei o código

Comment: é possível @hugocsl transformar tudo do form em imagem? Assim ela salva a imagem no tamanho certo e dps manda imprimir a imagem, sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Cara acho que com alguma API em PHP ou Python vc consegue capturar um "print" da tela e talvez já abrir para impressão. Outra coisa. Acho que essa mudança de tamanho pode ser pq a config da sua impressora está para "ajustar mídia a área de impressão" ou algo assim. O problema da Imprimir é que pelo browser não conseguimos mudas as configs da impressora do usuário. Acho que nessa não consigo te ajudar muito mais... Mas da uma olhada nesse artigo que as vezes tem algo que te interessa https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer o que preciso,transformando o form em html2canvas.js vou deixar o código inteiro aqui, pode ajudar as pessoas.

```
    <?php
//header('Content-type: image/png'); 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consulta Código - Resposta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/canvas2image.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
  @media print
{
    * {-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}
}
 @media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printable, #printable * {
    visibility: visible;


  }


} 
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<?php


class WBarCode {
    var $_fino;
    var $_largo;
    var $_altura;
    var $BarCodes = array();
    var $texto;
    var $matrizimg;
    var $f1;
    var $f2;
    var $f;
    var $i;

    function WBarCode($Valor){
        $this->fino=3;
        $this->largo=5;
        $this->altura=46;

        if (empty($this->BarCodes[0]))
        {
            $this->BarCodes[0]="00110";
            $this->BarCodes[1]="10001";
            $this->BarCodes[2]="01001";
            $this->BarCodes[3]="11000";
            $this->BarCodes[4]="00101";
            $this->BarCodes[5]="10100";
            $this->BarCodes[6]="01100";
            $this->BarCodes[7]="00011";
            $this->BarCodes[8]="10010";
            $this->BarCodes[9]="01010";

            for ($this->f1=9; $this->f1>=0; $this->f1=$this->f1-1)
            {
                for ($this->f2=9; $this->f2>=0; $this->f2=$this->f2-1)
                {
                    $this->f=$this->f1*10+$this->f2;
                    $this->texto="";
                    for ($this->i=1; $this->i<=5; $this->i=$this->i+1)
                    {
                        $this->texto=$this->texto.substr($this->BarCodes[$this->f1],$this->i-1,1).
                            substr($this->BarCodes[$this->f2],$this->i-1,1);
                    }
                    $this->BarCodes[$this->f]=$this->texto;
                }
            }
        }

        $this->matrizimg.= "
<img src=p.gif width=$this->fino height=$this->altura border=0><img 
src=b.gif width=$this->fino height=$this->altura border=0><img
src=p.gif width=$this->fino height=$this->altura border=0><img
src=b.gif width=$this->fino height=$this->altura border=0><img 
";

        $this->texto=$Valor;
        if (strlen($this->texto)%2<>0)
        {
            $this->texto="0".$this->texto;
        }

        while(strlen($this->texto)>0)
        {
            $this->i=intval(substr($this->texto,0,2));
            $this->texto=substr($this->texto,strlen($this->texto)-(strlen($this->texto)-2));
            $this->f=$this->BarCodes[$this->i];
            for ($this->i=1; $this->i<=10; $this->i=$this->i+2)
            {
                if (substr($this->f,$this->i-1,1)=="0")
                {
                    $this->f1=$this->fino;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->f1=$this->largo;
                }

                $this->matrizimg.="src=p.gif width=$this->f1 height=$this->altura border=0><img 
    ";
                if (substr($this->f,$this->i+1-1,1)=="0")
                {

                    $this->f2=$this->fino;
                }
                else
                {

                    $this->f2=$this->largo;
                }

                $this->matrizimg.= "src=b.gif width=$this->f2 height=$this->altura border=0><img ";
            }
        }

        $this->matrizimg.= "src=p.gif width=$this->largo height=$this->altura border=0><img src=b.gif width=$this->fino height=$this->altura border=0><img 
src=p.gif width=1 height=$this->altura border=0>";

        echo $this->matrizimg;

    }//fim da function
}//fim da Class


$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];


?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 120px;margin-left: 120px;">

<form id="capture" style="width: 5.4cm;height: 8.4cm;background-image: url(imagens/teste.png); background-size: 5.4cm 8.4cm">

    <?php
        include('conexao.php');

        $consulta = oci_parse($conexao, "select A.CRACHA, c.codigo, c.estab, a.codigo, c.nome, c.nomeguerra  from absis.equipe c, absis.crachas a  where c.codigo = a.cracha and  a.cracha = '$codigo'");
    oci_execute($consulta);
        while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($consulta)) != false) {


            $nome = $row['NOME'];
            $nomeguerra = $row['NOMEGUERRA'];
          //  $imagem = $row['FOTO']->load();
           // $estab = $row['ESTAB'];

            if ( !isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) ) {
     //     $erro = 'Nada foi postado.';
                echo '<script> alert (" Codigo Inexistente !"); location.href=("index.php")</script>';
            }
             //     echo '<script> alert (" Codigos Inexistentes !"); location.href=("index.php")</script>';
              //  echo " xxx";
            else {



                ?>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 4.3cm;">


                        <!-- <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $imagem );  ?>" width="145" height="179" style="border-radius: 7px"/><br> -->
                        <center><p style='font-size: 20px'><b><?php echo $nomeguerra ?></b></p></center>
                        <center><p style='font-size: 11px;margin-top: -20px;padding-left: 5px'><b><?php echo $nome ?></b></p></center>
        <?php
                        $string = str_replace(" ","",$codigo);



         ?>
   <!-- <div align="center" >  <?php $bar = new WBarCode("$string"); ?> </div> -->


                </div>


<?php } } ?>







</form>
  <p style="padding-left: 9px">Verificação de Dados</p>

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 120px;margin-left: 120px;">
<div id="img-out"></div>
<p style="padding-left: 9px">Imagem para Impressão</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">

<div class="container" style="margin-left: 120px">
<form id="capture2" style="width: 5.7cm;height: 9cm;background-image: url(imagens/teste2.png); background-size: 5.7cm 9cm; ">

    <?php
        include('conexao.php');

        $consulta = oci_parse($conexao, "select A.CRACHA, c.codigo, c.estab, a.codigo, c.nome, c.nomeguerra  from absis.equipe c, absis.crachas a  where c.codigo = a.cracha and  a.cracha = '$codigo'");
    oci_execute($consulta);
        while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($consulta)) != false) {

            $codigo = $row['CODIGO'];
            $cracha = $row['CRACHA'];

          //  $imagem = $row['FOTO']->load();
           // $estab = $row['ESTAB'];

            if ( !isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) ) {
     //     $erro = 'Nada foi postado.';
                echo '<script> alert (" Codigo Inexistente !"); location.href=("index.php")</script>';
            }
             //     echo '<script> alert (" Codigos Inexistentes !"); location.href=("index.php")</script>';
              //  echo " xxx";
            else {



                ?>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 7.2cm">


                        <!-- <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $imagem );  ?>" width="145" height="179" style="border-radius: 7px"/><br> -->
                        <!--<center><p style='font-size: 20px'><b><?php echo $nomeguerra ?></b></p></center>
                        <p style='font-size: 12px;margin-top: -15px;padding-left: 37px'><b><?php echo $nome ?></b></p> -->
        <?php
                        $string = str_replace(" ","",$codigo);



         ?>
    <div align="center" >  <?php $bar = new WBarCode("$string"); ?> </div>
    <?php

    echo "<center style='margin-top: -7px'><font style='font-size: 9px;color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma;'>$cracha</font></center>";
    ?>

                </div>


<?php } } ?>







</form>
 <p style="padding-left: 9px">Verificação de Dados</p>
</div> 

</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="container" style="margin-left: 120px;">
<div id="img-out2"></div>
<p style="padding-left: 9px">Imagem para Impressão</p>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    $("#img-out").append(canvas);
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture2")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    $("#img-out2").append(canvas);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```